# Prove that if n is a positive integer such that the sum of its divisors is n+1, then n is prime.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

[image]

I think this proof is way too vague and doesn't work. Is there another way to prove this?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's too vague"?

Comment: The only thing wrong with the proof is that the penultimate line should read *Therefore there are no **other** divisors of* $n$ (or *Therefore there are no **proper** divisors of* $n$). Otherwise it’s a fine proof.

Comment: Does divisors mean it should be divisible by anything? what if i said 3 was a divisor? That's what I mean. Am I thinking wrong?

Comment: Here's what I think is wrong with the proof: it starts by saying that "$1$ and $n$ are divisors of $n$", and then says "therefore there are no divisors of $n$".  What it *should* say is "therefore there are no **other** divisors of $n$".

Comment: Should I have to prove that to though? That there are no other divisors of n? Is what I'm getting at.

Comment: @Gabby one number can be a divisor *of another number*, but we don't simply say that a number "is a divisor".  So, for example: $3$ is a divisor of $9$, but $4$ is not a divisor of $9$.  The statement "$3$ is a divisor" is not meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

The divisors of $n$ include obviously $1$ and $n$; so their sum is $\geq n+1$. If it is $n+1$ than n is prime by definition (its divisor are only n and 1).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe a variant by contrapositive will be clearer?

If $n$ is not prime, it has at least one non-trivial divisor $1<m<n$. Hence the sum of its divisors is at least $1+m+n>n+1$.